# gzserver is not responding on Windows 10

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-melodic, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I've installed ROS on a Windows 10 machine using [this official guide](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows). When I run `gzserver` in a ROS Command Window, it basically does nothing. On Task Manager, it says Not Responding for the process with the name gzserver.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338118/gzserver-is-not-responding-on-windows-10/) by [mbd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26651/mbd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

gzserver is waiting for a connection.
(It doesn't service a message loop which is why it appears to be hung.)

Try launching it through ROS:
`roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch`

---

Originally posted by [OoeyGUI](https://answers.ros.org/users/37999/ooeygui/) with karma: 186 on 2019-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mbd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26651/mbd/) on 2019-11-22**:
Thanks! It works.